# Exported activity for (local) file editing

Tags: android, android-manifest, intentfilter

I want my app to appear as an option when user tries to open a file from a file manager. Its purpose is to edit only local files.
So this is what I came up with (this is in the manifest file):

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityOpen"
          android:exported="true">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE"/> <!-- Probably ignored by most file managers. -->
        <data android:mimeType="text/*"/> <!-- "text/*" is just an example, I tried other mime-types as well. -->
    </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

But my app does not show in the menu for app selection at all. What do I need to do so it does?

Comment: How should a file manager know that a user wants to edit a file? How dou you know that the file manager uses sn EDIT intent?

Comment: @blackapps It looks to me that it's practically a standard. I also tried `VIEW` and even `SEND` but the same problem persists.